# I want the data in input fields to be removed when I click on the current page link

Tags: angular, typescript

I work with Angular 8. I added `onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'` to my `router` in order to make the second click on the same link reload the page. It works fine but it doesn't empty the input fields on the reloaded page. Why is that so and how can I fix it?

Comment: Form has default values?

Comment: No it doesn't. @RafaelPizao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'` reruns the router but it keeps active the already rendered component and so on its current state.
A workaround is to listen to router events into the component, acting when the navigation ends :

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events.pipe(
      // when the navigation ends
      filter((event: RouterEvent) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe(() => {
      // empty the input fiels programatically
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you please specify how should I define the "filter"?

Comment: it should be fine this way : each time the router is activated on your application, it goes through a list of events (https://angular.io/api/router/Event). As NavigationEnd means the navigation ended with success (passing through guards, resolver), it's a good pointer.